# checking internet connectivity for cellular networks in ios using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, reachability, connectivity, cellular-network

I have used a solution from stack Overflow to check internet connectivity Its is working for wifi networks but not for cellular network

```
public class YASConnectivity {
class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

    var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
    zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
    zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

    guard let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress, {
        SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0))
    }) else {
        return false
    }

    var flags : SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = []
    if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags) {
        return false
    }

    let isReachable = flags.contains(.Reachable)
    let needsConnection = flags.contains(.ConnectionRequired)
    return (isReachable && !needsConnection)
}

}
```

How can I check Internet connectivity for cellular networks ?

I am getting this error when trying Rock's solution

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try using this third party lib:
[Reachability](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift)

and write this code:

```
let reachability = Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()

reachability?.whenReachable = { reachability in
    // keep in mind this is called on a background thread
    // and if you are updating the UI it needs to happen
    // on the main thread, like this:
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        if reachability.isReachableViaWiFi() {
            print("Reachable via WiFi")
        } else {
            print("Reachable via Cellular")
        }
    }
}
reachability?.whenUnreachable = { reachability in
    // keep in mind this is called on a background thread
    // and if you are updating the UI it needs to happen
    // on the main thread, like this:
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        print("Not reachable")
    }
}

reachability?.startNotifier()
```

Comment: Where exactly do I need to perform this ?

Comment: @Byte You can perform it in your main view controller or app delegate, I suggest using an object which wrappers it so you can have a clean code. Anywaym the first step could be call it in the app delegate in did launch with options delegate

Comment: can you please update your answer in a form of a function that returns bool for connectivity ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First of all add Reachability.swift file into your project and use this code.

```
class func checkNetworkConnection() -> Bool 
{
    let reachable = Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()

    if reachable.isReachable() || reachable.isReachableViaWiFi()
    {
        return true
    }
    else
    {
        print("Mobile Data")
       return false

    }
}
```

i hope it help...

Comment: Lets say I have turend On my mobile data. but I have no Internet connectivity. Will this work ?

Comment: it will only print mobile data.

Comment: Im sorry its not working for cellular networks. It returns true if my mobile data is ON and I do not have any internet package.